# dropdown is not open when using context

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to use both context and static approach for more flexible dropdown so i can use any element to show in the dropdown title(may be button or icon or just text or anything that is relevant). However, my dropdown is not toggled. I mean **toggleMenu function is not triggered** so that it can ensure whether to show the dropdown item or not.

Here is how i have done

```
class Title extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Dropdown.Consumer>
        {({ showMenu, toggleMenu }) => {
          return (
            <React.Fragment>
              <DropdownTitle>
                {React.cloneElement(this.props.children, {
                  showMenu,
                  onClick: () => toggleMenu()
                })}
              </DropdownTitle>
            </React.Fragment>
          );
        }}
      </Dropdown.Consumer>
    );
  }
}

class Item extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Dropdown.Consumer>
        {({ showMenu }) => {
          return (
            <React.Fragment>
              {showMenu && <DropdownItem>{this.props.children}</DropdownItem>}
            </React.Fragment>
          );
        }}
      </Dropdown.Consumer>
    );
  }
}

const DropdownContext = React.createContext();

class Dropdown extends Component<Props> {
  static Title = Title;
  static Item = Item;
  static Consumer = DropdownContext.Consumer;

  state = {
    showMenu: false,
    toggleMenu: () => {}
  };

  toggleMenu = () => {
    console.log('did not trigger this function when clicking')
    this.setState(
      prevState => ({
        showMenu: !prevState.showMenu
      }),
      () => this.props.toggleState(this.state.showMenu)
    );
  };

  render() {
    const { children } = this.props;
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <DropdownContext.Provider value={{ ...this.state }}>
          {children}
        </DropdownContext.Provider>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}

export default Dropdown;
```

I have created a sandbox either. Here it is

https://codesandbox.io/s/k3lw98jlov

Comment: What is the problem you are having exactly? Please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so that it will be easier for someone to help you.

Comment: I am clearly stating the issue that my toggleMenu is not triggered when clicking the dropdown title which you can see in the workaround as well.

Answer (score 0):

I think there are some issues with your code. First how you use the context value. There is no way of getting to the function because you don't provide it. I'd do it like so:

```
<DropdownContext.Provider value={{ ...this.state, toggleMenu: this.togglemenu }}>
          {children}
</DropdownContext.Provider>
```

otherwise the toggelmenu function is just an empty function (you need to remove it from the state).

Second I took a quick look at the sandbox and I don't really see where the context is used, i.d. where the function should be called. Make sure you use the context at the right place. I think what you need to do is to connect the index.js to the context, because here you are *listening* for a button-click. Correct me if I am wrong or if I didn't understand something properly.

Hope that helps.

Regards

Comment: I passed toggleMenu as you have said but its still not working.  I did not quite understand "Make sure you use the context at the right place". Can you help me by commenting in the codesandbox, please? https://codesandbox.io/s/k3lw98jlov